# Tapping on a word in a UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitextview

I want to allow users to type some text in my iPhone app, and when they tap/touch a word or sentence, then call a method on that word.

My problem is how do I do it?

I got the idea from from the app AudioNote: http://luminantsoftware.com/iphone/audionote.html

Does anyone know how to go about it?!

Comment: you need to dig CoreText

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they may be using a UIWebView to display the text. This gives you the advantage of being able to apply different formatting to individual words.

To handle tapping on words you could create them as hyperlinks and detect the touches using:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

**oops, sorry forgot about entering the text. Don't know how to do that with a webview.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "call a method on that word"?

Where I would start looking would be in the [UITextView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) and the [UITextViewDelegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html)

If I understand what you want to do, you might be able to do it with the UITextViewDelegate method

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
```

Comment: Sorry for my english. What i want to do is, when a user tabs on a sentence, I'd like to be notified.